# RestKit and apportable - error: expected a type

Tags: restkit, apportable

I'm just trying to get my app woking with appportable and I keep getting the following error from RestKit while compiling

```
/Pods/Headers/RestKit/RestKit/CoreData/RKManagedObjectStore.h:246:78: error: 
       expected a type

 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:    (NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType...
```

Has anyone come across this before..?

Comment: Are you using the 0.10.x or 0.20.x RestKit?

After a few modifications I got apportable to compile the 0.10.x RestKit, but haven't tried 0.20.x yet.

Comment: Any luck? Have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apportable does not yet implement NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.

```
~/.apportable  $  cd ~/.apportable/SDK/System/
~/.apportable/SDK/System  $ grep -r NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType *
~/.apportable/SDK/System  $
```

If you're not using that part of RestKit, you could comment out the code causing the warning. Otherwise, currently you'd need to reimplement it with other API's.